# Get the latest/recent file from FTP to local using Talend

Tags: file, ftp, talend, file-management

I have to create a job in Talend which will connect to One FTP. The FTP is having various files for each day with same prefix but different timestamp appended(yyyymmddhhmmss) in the filename.
Example -

> MyFile20151123142020.xml
>   MyFile20151123154748.xml

My requirement is to pick the latest or most recent file and copy to my local.
I understand that this could be achieved either by referring to the latest timestamp in the filename or referring to the last modified time. I thought of proceeding with the later and my job looks like below - 
[image]

[image]

I dont know how to proceed further and how to use the latest mtime value to pick the most recent file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting file properties, wen need to sort files by mtime or by basename then pick the first.

- tSortRow :  sort by mtime or basename if they have same pattern.
- tSampleRow : "1" to get the first
- tFTPGet : file mask = row3.basename (row3 the output flow of tSampleRow)

[image]

Comment: I have connected tsampleRow output to a tlogrow to see if it is picking the correct file..but it is not displaying any file.

Comment: @Meen please run your job in  debug mode to see the data flow, or put tlogrow after tFTPFileProperties.

Comment: I tried connecting the tSamplerow to tftpget, but on pressing ctrl+space, i am unable to see the output row as basename. I could only see ((String)globalMap.get("tSampleRow_1_ERROR_MESSAGE")) :(

Comment: @Meen just write: row3.basename where row3 is the row that connect tSampleRow and TFTPGet

Comment: I wrote row3.basename in the ftpget filemask but the file was not picked. So, i tried displaying its value using tjava. I wrote -   
System.out.println((String)globalMap.get("row7.basename"));

But it displayed NULL.
I am confused now...  :(

Comment: @Meen You cannot use tJava to deal with rows instead use tJavaRow or more easier tLogRow, if you are sure that tSampleRow pick the first row then row7.basename will work !